# How to add Page to Navigation queue without displaying

Tags: wpf, navigation

I would like to pre-populate my WPF Navigation queue with Pages, so that in code I just need to call `.GoForward()` and `.GoBack()` (in this case I will only have 2 Pages to deal with) on my `Frame` and not worry about `.Navigate()` calling logic in the middle of the code.  Is this possible?

Comment: Navigation , is that like in a BAML application ?

Comment: @eranotzap No BAML is binary XAML.  Maybe you are thinking of an [XBAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970060.aspx)?  (If so, yes.)